# How to make "find" command slow

Tags: linux, centos, server

You read it right: I want to make the "find" command of Linux slower and using less system resources. I created a cronjob that runs the find command once every 10 minutes but when it runs the find command uses almost all my CPU for about 3 minutes, leaving almost nothing left to my SO.

So I would like to be able to make the "find" command run a little slower so it does not use so much resources of my Centos server and run steady in the 10 minutes instead of using all resources for 3 minutes.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is this somehow related to programming?

Comment: Are you sure that you need the cron job to run every 10 minutes?  Are you sure you need it to look at so much of your system?  If you slow the `find` command down by much, you're going to have the cron job that is started on the hour still running when the next cron job runs ten minutes later, and that's probably as bad as having the one running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups):

> The nice command tweaks the priority level of a process so that it runs less frequently. This is useful when you need to run a CPU intensive task as a background or batch job. The niceness level ranges from -20 (most favorable scheduling) to 19 (least favorable). Processes on Linux are started with a niceness of 0 by default. The nice command (without any additional parameters) will start a process with a niceness of 10. At that level the scheduler will see it as a lower priority task and give it less CPU resources.

So you can simply wrap your task inside a `nice` which will change the priority of the task.

Change

```
whatever
```

To

```
nice whatever
```

Comment: I have never heard of this and it solved my problem, freaking amazing!

Comment: @Samul Glad it helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it slow down **internally** unless you can recompile the codes and add some delay function..

here is how can can slow down  or delay the find command iteration execution

```
find -type f -exec sh -c 'echo {};sleep 1'  \;
```

make it sleep every 1 second before printing the file name or (whatever codes you prefer to execute.)